# Server pushing with Web API

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a client app (WP8) and a Web API.  The app can send messages to other users via the Web API (usually one other user, sometimes a few).  This is done with a simple "AppMessage" class which is saved via a post to the Web API.

I would like to make this a much quicker process.  At the moment a user is only informed of a message when they log on (authenticate via Web API), or when they click the refresh button in the app - at which point the client goes and checks for more messages.

SignalR seems to fit here.  Is it possible to notify connecting clients of messages that were sent to them when they weren't connected?  I would need to map the SignalR connection to a user record in the database and retrieve saved messages sent to them.

I understand its use for real-time communication, but not how it deals with saving messages (or signals) to send to a client when it connects.

Thanks for any direction on this!

Comment: I think a better fit would possibly be Azure Notification Hubs: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/

Comment: This looks like exactly what im looking for!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If messages are stored in a database, for example, then you can check for them when the client connects (see [OnConnected](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime) method) and send them to the client.

SignalR itself doesn't implement storage for offline users or connections, so you need to implement that yourself.
Basically you need to check whether a user is online, and then either send the message directly or store it somewhere. You could make the client send a receipt to make sure your messages have actually been displayed.
Check [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections) for how to associate users with SignalR connections.

That said, I'd also recommend taking a closer look at Brendan's suggestion if you're using Azure.